# Android Studio 2.1 failed to connect to google cloud platform VCS

Tags: version-control, repository, google-cloud-platform, android-studio-2.1

after updating to 2.1 i can't push version to google cloud platform repository, the error message  :
**"Push failed, Failed with error: fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password."**

but i can't find the place to enter the username or password, android studio is signed in to my google account, it's happening in two different pc's, someone know what can be the reason and how to solve ?

Comment: Are you still encountering the issue or you were able to fix it?

Comment: The issue is solved, check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem solved by running  this line "git config --system --unset credential.helper",  [for more details](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-cloud-sdk/8SfiaKEYXTM)